# 7Zip does not exit after processing large zip file compression

Tags: java, 7zip, processbuilder

I am writing a java program on windows platform. I need to compress certain files into a zip archive. I am using ProcessBuilder to start a new 7zip process:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("7Z","a",zipPath,filePath);
Process p = processBuilder.start();
p.waitFor();
```

The problem is that the 7zip process never exits after completion. It does create the required zip file but after that just hangs in there. This means that the `waitFor()` call never returns and my program gets stuck. Please suggest a fix or a work around.

Comment: sometimes the problems with calling processes is that you need to process / clear the output the produce. once their output buffer is full, they wait for the buffer to come free again..

Comment: Did you know Java has a zip package to read/write zip files?  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. I just redirected output to a file

Comment: @user434541: You can answer your own question. Just put your solution here and mark it as accepted solution. That way you will help others in finding a solution in future and cleaning up of SO pending question queue :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what I ended up doing.

I can't set enviroment variables so I had to set the c: path for 7zip.

```
    public void zipMultipleFiles (List<file> Files, String destinationFile){
        String zipApplication = "\"C:\\Program Files\7Zip\7zip.exe\" a -t7z"; 
        String CommandToZip = zipApplication + " ";    
        for (File file : files){
           CommandToZip = CommandToZip + "\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\" ";
        }
        CommandToZip = CommandToZip + " -mmt -mx5 -aoa";
        runCommand(CommandToZip);
    }

    public void runCommand(String commandToRun) throws RuntimeException{
        Process p = null;
        try{
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun);
            String response = convertStreamToStr(p.getInputStream());
            p.waitFor();
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal Command ZippingFile");
        } finally {
            if(p = null){
                throw new RuntimeException("Illegal Command Zipping File");
            }
            if (p.exitValue() != 0){
                throw new Runtime("Failed to Zip File - unknown error");
            }
        }
    }
```

The convert to string function can be found here which is what I used as a reference. http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/getting-started-with-javas-processbuilder-a-sample-utility-class-to-interact-with-linux-from-java-program/